# SQL Server Management Studio SSMS tries to "save to file" instead of execute on F5

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

This happens intermittently and seems to be related to accidentally hitting a key.

Any ideas what causes this?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

It sounds like you have accidentally changed from the default query option of "Results to Grid" to "Results to File".  If that is the case it is easy to fix:

> From the Query Menu -> Results To ->
>   Results To Grid.
>
> OR
>
> Press Ctrl + D

Once you have tried one of the steps above, run your query again by pressing F5.

Comment: Ah ha! ctrl + shift + F (which is global search in VS2008) puts me in that mode. Thanks!

Comment: The command to switch to "Results to Grid" is Ctrl + Shift + D (at least for for SSMS 2016)

Answer (score 36):

Previous answer didn't apply to me. My query results were set to grid already (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

The issue is, if you're using a Microsoft ergo keyboard and the function lock (key to the right of <kbd>F12</kbd> usually) is not on, then <kbd>F5</kbd> will bring up an open file dialog by default.

So, yet another embarrassing resolution is: Keep F lock on! :)

On many laptops, there is no dedicated key for this, but often there is a keypress that will be equivalent, such as for dell laptops: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> or the [All in One Media Keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-do-iuse-the-fn-key-f-lock-key-alternate-command-keys-fccfaf23-38f0-88a8-9b44-a18f24523b79):<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can also get stuck in this mode (like I did) by accidentally pushing the "Results to File" **button** in the toolbar in SSMS.  Click the "Results to Text" or "Results to Grid" as desired and you'll be back to your usual, expected behavior.

[image]